# $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] not showing www.example.com

Tags: php, dns

Why does `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` not echo the `www` in `www.example.com` but it does work when I echo it from a sub domain like `test.example.com`?

Comment: `example.com` is probably the canonical server name of your server/virtual host. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t know why it doesn’t contain the expected value. But try [`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) instead, that contains the value provided by the client in the [HTTP header field *Host*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23). But see [Chris Shiftlett’s *`SERVER_NAME` Versus `HTTP_HOST`*](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host) for security considerations.

Comment: So, is HTTP_HOST safer than SERVER_NAME?

Comment: @Andreas: No, both are vulnerable, as the linked article describes. You should validate that values before using them. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459739