# What is required to run modx evolution on server type https

Tags: php, https, modx, modx-evolution

I have a site that is http and the customer wants it to be https. The site is running on MODX Evolution 1.0.6.

What is required to run that http site as https? I know that I need a certificate, but do I need to change code that works as http to work as https or can I just "flip the switch" from http to https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your templates for links using http - specifically that base href tag, check all your system variables for the same... then check all your javascripts etc for the same ... finally you will probably have to use mod rewrite to force all your traffic through https. This looks like it will do the trick:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239739/need-to-redirect-all-traffic-to-https
```