# Mixed secure/not secure message from Chrome

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, google-chrome, ssl

Just installed an SSL for my website and I'm facing 2 issues:

1- https:// isn't added by default, am I supposed to redirect to https:// with .htaccess or did I mess something up during instalaltion

2- I get this message "Your connection to www.MYWEBSITE.com is encrypted using 128-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit....", I check the console for the error logs, all of it is errors from me linking images from my subdomain, my image folder, and an IMGUR image.

Eg: The page at https://www.website.com/forums/ displayed insecure content from http://www.website.com/forums/images/theme/buttons/collapse_thead.gif.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Change the image URL from http to https

Comment: I got well over 300 images, is there a quick .htaccess fix? 

And what about the answer for issue #1 

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is little tricky. Approach should be:

1. Check if REFERRER page is using `htts://`
2. If yes then redirect `http to https` for all image, js, css files

Based on above approach following `mod_rewrite` rules should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https:// [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|css|js)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Can you try commenting out `RewriteCond` line?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably your application generating URLs to the images without HTTPS.
Have a look here how to rewrite all requests to HTTPS: [Need to redirect all traffic to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239739/need-to-redirect-all-traffic-to-https)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thanks, this some what worked, but not 100%. issues I faced: 1- SSL didn't show on pages that redirected to places, also the error was still showing.

Comment: Do you include any 3rd party libraries from a CDN (e.g. hosted jquery)? Or perhaps other files that are not hosted on your own server? And I am not sure I understand what you mean by "didn't show on pages that redirected"?

Comment: I include hosted 3rd party jqueries yes, and I've fixed the other part.

Comment: Is the hosted jquery also included over https? If not, that probably causes the error. Best thing to do is check the source of your page, and search for any "http://" urls being used. See if you can change those to https as well.