# How can i get my website to display as https://www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This question is not a duplicate of any other, please read in full. I have scoured the whole internet for answers.

We want our whole website to display as https://www

Basically https:// will not redirect to https://www

Thought i'd fixed the issue with this...

> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.`
>
> `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]`
>
> `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
>
> `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1`

but when we do this the homepage redirects work fine but every other page has the end of the url repeated twice for example /printing.htmlprinting.html

How can we get everything to display for https://www

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to redirect all traffic to https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239739/need-to-redirect-all-traffic-to-https)

Comment: I've looked at every result on this site about this. It's not duplicate because i want  it to display as https://www

Comment: Actually you are probably right it's more likely a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Comment: No because http://w w w was redirecting me to https://w w w. Matter is solved and Croises answer fixed the issue. Just to reiterate the issue was that http:// & http://w w w were redirecting to https://w w w fine however https:// would not redirect to https://w w w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this (without final $1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```