# .htaccess to redirect an OldDomain to a NewDomain including HTTPs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have searched an .htaccess that redirects all the traffic from an Old Site to a New one (including HTTPS) but I have not found it.

Actually I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# First rule - if this is an SSL connection, then redirect
# to http://example.com then stop processing other rules
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.OldDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Second rule - all other requests, redirect to http://newdomain.com.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.NewDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And this one works perfect for these situations:

```
http://OldDomain.com/                > https://www.NewDomain.com/
http://OldDomain.com/internal/       > https://www.NewDomain.com/internal/
http://www.OldDomain.com/            > https://www.NewDomain.com/
http://www.OldDomain.com/internal/   > https://www.NewDomain.com/internal/

https://OldDomain.com/               > https://www.NewDomain.com/
https://www.OldDomain.com/           > https://www.NewDomain.com/
```

But these situations with HTTPS don't:

```
https://OldDomain.com/internal/
https://www.OldDomain.com/internal/
```

What I have missing in my .htaccess?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

- Put this on root `.htaccess` of old : (old to new)

  ```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
  rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
  ```
- Put this in the root .`htaccess` of new : (http to https)

  `RewriteEngine on`

  `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`

  `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Refer : [redirect all traffic to https](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3239775/2142994)

Comment: Hello.... In the 
    Put this on root .htaccess  of old :
appears domain.com appeas in line 3 and 4 Is OldDomain or NewDomain?

Comment: first one would be old & second one new.

Answer (score 0):

If the new domain is  pointing to a diffrent web server, You can also use mod-alias instead of using mod-rewrite :

Add the following line to your olddomain/.htaccss :

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.newdomain.com/
```

This will forword all requests to the new domain.

Reference

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: It don't works... http://OldDomain.com/internal/ redirects to https://www.NewDomain.cominternal/

Comment: @Gabotron oops! I forgot the trailing slash, see the edit