# HTTPS redirect issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to force all request to `HTTPS` rather than `HTTP`.

For that I have added the following code in to my `.htaccess` as can be seen below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This URL is forced to `HTTPS`: http://localhost/test

but this URL is not forced to `HTTPS`: http://localhost/test/public/assets/css/custom.css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to redirect all traffic to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239739/need-to-redirect-all-traffic-to-https)

Comment: Please do a simple google search before asking a question. How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @RiggsFolly i find everywhere but not getting any solution, try yourself using above code and make sure above 2 URL cases working perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This is straight from the Apache documentation:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

It doesn't look much different than yours but perhaps the minor changes will make a difference with your specific issue.