# Grabbing entry domain for a site

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have several domains that point to the same site, some of them ending in ".br" (domain for Brazil, thus for portuguese speakers)

I want to detect from what domain the person came (.br or not) and load the correct landuage...

I can use PHP, JavaScript or standard HTML/CSS etc... How I do it? (and with what?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the server side, use the `HTTP_HOST` variable which is basically the `Host` header and a fool-proof way of checking the host the request was sent to.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name) for a nice comparison between `SERVER_NAME` and the `HTTP_HOST` variables.

On the client side, use [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain). For this page - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain, the value of `document.domain` is

```
"developer.mozilla.org"
```

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] should get that information.  But this is not a sure fire way. Some people have the referrer turned off or spoofed in their browsers etc. This is the only way that I would know how, unless you can append get data to the urls on the domain to set the language etc. Then you just check for that get data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on PHP5.3+ you can use

[`Locale::acceptFromHttp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php) — Tries to find out best available locale based on HTTP "Accept-Language" header

If not, you can still determine it from Accept-Language header yourself. Using the Accept Header should be somewhat more reliable than using the TLD, especially if you also need to use any of the [other intl extensions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php).

Comment: Please keep in mind that intl is a [PEAR extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl) and has to be installed seperately.  It does not come built in to PHP.  **Accept-Language** is the best way to determine a user's language, regardless of whether you get it from an extension or read the header yourself in `$_SERVER`

Comment: @Charles `intl` is a native extension as of PHP5.3 and does no longer need to be installed separately.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case with the distribution of 5.3 I have here.  I'm not sure whether that's because the packages I'm using weren't compiled with it, or whether I'm missing the underlying ICU library.

Comment: It looks like the person that built the distro did so with "--enable-intl=shared" and packaged it separately.  Irritating, I wish they'd leave the default compile options alone.  How am I supposed to get a consistent environment if they keep changing the rules?  Argh!  Therefore, I stand by my original statement, modified: `intl` might not be available if your package maintainer futzed with the build options, but there's always PECL.