# Getting hostname or IP address of server in PHP

Tags: php, url

I basically need to create a anchor that will navigate to a different port on the server. For instance, our server is hosted on `domain.com:555`, we need a link to navigate to `domain.com:777`. The catch is that it's not always domain.com. We can expect the DNS to malfunction, in which case we will use ip address to navigate like `xx.xx.xx.xx:555` and `xx.xx.xx.xx:777`.

I need get the hostname of the server where the PHP script is running. I tried using SERVER_ADDR, but that for reason gives me the private IP of the server.

So how do I get the domain / ip part of the url?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

From the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) predefined variable, which, for `'HTTP_HOST'` contains:

> Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.

You might also find:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

useful, and [this Stack Overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name/2297421#2297421) of their relative merits instructive.

Comment: Which? `HTTP_HOST` or `SERVER_NAME`? The answer to both is probably no - go read that discussion I linked to!

Comment: @gAMBOOKa - It is always reliable provided your server has not outputted the host name in the header, which is highly unlikely if it is a web hosting server.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa I think the bottom line is, it's as reliable as it gets. If you want to be 1000% sure, use a hard coded setting in your app.

Comment: @webfac: the host header is REQUIRED if you're on a name-based virtual host. As such HTTP_HOST will always have the name the site was accessed by. SERVER_NAME is what the webserver's been configured to call itself, which is not necessarily the site it's serving.

Answer (score 3):

Try `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` this will give you the host name / domain name

Comment: @Dominic Rodger - Apologies for double posting your answer, I only saw your response after I posted, the credit is yours!