# $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] contains port number too =/

Tags: php, virtual-hosts, superglobals, port-number

I don't know maybe it's a bug.

I have 2 virutalhosts on my server.

virtualhost1.com
virtualhost2.com

if i open virtualhost1.com with port 80 (virtualhost1.com:80)

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='virtualhost1.com';
```

but if i open virtualhost2.com:80

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='virtualhost2.com:80'; // NOTE: with port number
```

Can I know why?

Comment: I suggest posting your VirtualHost definitions.

Comment: And I suggest rtfm http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is taken directly from the `Host:` HTTP request header. It appears the requesting client is filling it in that way.

I suggest using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead as its value will be set from your virtual host config. However, as Flimm notes below, even the reliability of `SERVER_NAME` can still be dependent on server config (check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name) for more info on that).

Comment: Note that it's a bit more complicated than that, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` can't always be trusted. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name)

Answer (score 1):

Following function always return real host (user typed host) without port and it's almost reliable:

```
function getRealHost(){
   list($realHost,)=explode(':',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
   return $realHost;
}
```

Comment: Just `return strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ':', true);`

Comment: @lawrence-cherone this will return an empty string if no ':' character is found. It's better to use `strtok($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ':');`