# How to print current URL path?

Tags: php, url

I want to print out the current URL path, but my code doesn't work propperly.

I use this in my file.php

```
echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

When i open the url **http://sub.mydomain.com/file.php** it seems to work fine, and it prints `"http://sub.mydomain.com/file.php"`

But if i remove the .php extension so the url will be **http://sub.mydomain.com/file** instead, it prints `"http://sub.mydomain.com/sub/file.php"` which is wrong.

It prints the subdomain twice, and I don't know why?

In my .htaccess file, I have a rewrite that makes it possible to removes .php extensions.

Anyone who can/want to help me please? :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, cos `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` will always give you the file which is working at the moment.

From manual:

> SCRIPT_NAME: Contains the current script's path. This is useful for pages which need to point to themselves. The `__FILE__` constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file. .

I suppose this helps you getting current URL fully.

```
echo 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Notice: DO NOT RELY ON CLIENT'S `HTTP_HOST`, USE `SERVER_NAME` INSTEAD! SEE: [What is the difference between HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name)

#### Security Warning

You need to filter (sanitize) `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if you use it in anywhere (to print or store in database), cos it's not safe.

```
// ie: this could be harmfull
/user?id=123%00%27<script...
```

Hence, always filter user inputs before using them. At least use `htmlspecialchars`, `htmlentities`, `strip_tags` etc..

Or something like this;

```
function get_current_url($strip = true) {
    static $filter, $scheme, $host, $port; 
    if ($filter == null) {
        $filter = function($input) use($strip) {
            $input = trim($input);
            if ($input == '/') {
                return $input;
            }

            // add more chars if needed
            $input = str_ireplace(["\0", '%00', "\x0a", '%0a', "\x1a", '%1a'], '',
                rawurldecode($input));

            // remove markup stuff
            if ($strip) {
                $input = strip_tags($input);
            }

            // or any encoding you use instead of utf-8
            $input = htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');

            return $input;
        };

        $scheme = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']
            : ('http'. (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '443') ? 's' : ''));
        $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $port = ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80' && $scheme != 'https')
            ? (':'. $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) : '';
        }
    }

    return sprintf('%s://%s%s%s', $scheme, $host, $port, $filter($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
}
```

Comment: Relying on HTTP_HOST is quite useful if your real serving host is behind proxy or using none standard ports

Answer (score 0):

```
$main_folder = str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__) );
$document_root = str_replace('\\','/',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );
$main_folder = str_replace( $document_root, '', $main_folder);
if( $main_folder ) {
    $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/' . ltrim( $main_folder, '/' ) . '/';
} else {
    $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.rtrim( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '/'). '/';
}
```

Comment: describe your answer

Comment: How to print current URL path?

$current_url -> current URL path

Comment: Fails on the latest MAMP on MacOS Sierra. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008135/is-serverrequest-scheme-reliable

Comment: $scheme = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] : 'http';
if( $main_folder ) {
    $current_url = $scheme.'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/' . ltrim( $main_folder, '/' ) . '/';
} else {
    $current_url = $scheme.'://'.rtrim( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '/'). '/';
}