# PHP: Get base URL of a page

Tags: php, url, path

### Scenario:

User adds a `URL` *(Like `URLs` below)*. I want to return all links on the page that appears in `href` attribute. I can get all links using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class. But some links are relative. I want to convert them to absolute links.

---

### My Problem:

Suppose I have these strings (`URLs`) *(User may sends any link. like **one** of these)*:

```
http://example.com/test/index.html
http://example.com/test/test.php
http://example.com/test/
http://example.com/test
```

Now I get all contents of the `href` of user's input `URL`. Some of these **URLs** are relative so I have to merge those relative links to the base `URL`. **My problem is that I cannot get the base URL.** In this example my base `URL` would be `http://example.com/test`. So if user enters any of those `URLs` above I have to get the same base `URL`.

How can I extract the URL base correctly?

Comment: Take a look at this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912943/how-to-print-current-url-path)

Comment: No. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` returns current php host. I don't want this. I want to get from a string.

Comment: If `test` is your script root directory and you have not already defined it within a constant then consider to do it.

Comment: Where do the strings come from? Maybe you can just check for the shortest string?

Comment: @RST They come from user input. Users enter a URL and I want to get all `href` links. INCLUDING relative links. And of course I need to convert them to absolute path.

Comment: @revo Yes. `test` is my root directory. I can't define it. some sites don't define it.

Comment: can you clarify that scenario please by updating the question. You said you are getting these strings from your users. However, it sounds like these are the links on the pages you are crawling instead. Also, note that the base url for a page can defined via the [`<base>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) so just looking at all the found urls won't necessarily be correct. On another side note, there's a [dozen existing Q&A on how to convert from relative to absolute links](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+all+relative+to+absolute+links+%5Bphp%5D)

Comment: I think you need to put more detail to your post. What do you mean by you want to get all href, are you crawling the domain?

Comment: I've completely updated my question. Please read it again. Thanks.

Comment: So you mean a base URL can be different every time?

Comment: @revo Depends on users's input yes. for example in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684680/php-get-base-url-of-a-page`, base URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684680/php-get-base-url-of-a-page` but in `http://example.com/index.html`, base URL is: `http://example.com`

Comment: What if `index.html` is a directory named that way?

Comment: then `/` would be necessary. like `eample.com/index.html/` otherwise it's counted as a file in browser.

Comment: What if `test` in `http://example.com/test` is a file name without an extension?

Answer (score -2):

**You can use parse_url method like this code:**

```
<?php 
    $url = 'http://example.com/test';
    //get base url from link
    $base_url=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    //get path from link
    $path=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    //print base_url
    echo 'Base URL = '.$base_url;
    //print path
    echo ' PATH = '.$path;
 ?>
```