# How to enable HTTPS for Wordpress MU main domain but not subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

I'm trying to write rules in my .htaccess file to default to HTTPS:// with my www.mainsite.com in my Wordpress MU network. For all other subdomains, is it possible to add a wildcard *.mainsite.com rule to treat newly created sites as HTTP only?

Here is my current .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mainsite\.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively, is it just as easy to declare specific subdomains to be treated as HTTPS and/or HTTP?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force SSL on only `mainsite.com` and `www.mainsite.com`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mainsite\.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

To add a new `subdomain` to your "force SSL" list

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www|subdomain)\.)?mainsite\.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

All other sub domains would use `http` by default.

Comment: Thanks! In case anyone is wondering the difference between HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME, I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name