# How to emulate mod_rewrite in PHP

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a few URLs that I want to map to certain files via PHP. Currently, I am just using mod_rewrite in Apache. However, my application is getting too large for the rewriting to be done with regular expressions. So I created a file `router.php` that does the rewriting. I understand to do a redirect I could just send the `Location:` header. However, I don't always want to do a redirect. For example, I may want `/api/item/` to map to the file `/herp/derp.php` relative to the document root. I need to preserve the HTTP method as well. "No problem," I thought. I made my `.htaccess` have the following snippet.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/item/$ /cgi-bin/router.php [L]
```

And my `router.php` file looks as follows:

```
<?php

$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$query = isset($uri['query']) ? $uri['query'] ? array();
// some code that modifies the query
require_once "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/herp/derp.php?" . http_build_query($query);

?>
```

However, this doesn't work, because the OS is looking for a file named `derp.php?some=query`. How can I simulate a rewrite rule such as `RewriteRule ^api/item/$ /herp/derp/ [L]` in PHP. In other words, how do I tell the server to process a different URL than requested and preserve the query and HTTP method without causing a redirect?

Note: Using variables set in `router.php` is less than desirable and is bad structure since it's only supposed to be responsible for handling URLs. I am open to using a light-weight third party solution.

Comment: you don't need to attach the query, its already there ... just `require_once "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/herp/derp.php"`

Comment: Sorry, just made an edit. I am actually modifying the query based on the URL requested. I forgot to put that detail in there.

Comment: Just modify it then ...  `$_GET['some_var'] = 'my modifications';`

Comment: Ah. Now I feel stupid. So obvious. Ha. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your .htaccess to read

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/item/$ /cgi-bin/router.php [QSA,L]
```

In your php

```
// update your get variables
$_GET['some_var'] = 'my modifications';

// require file
require_once "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/herp/derp.php"
```

Comment: Is the `QSA` flag really necessary in this case if Apache isn't modifying the query?

Comment: @TylerCrompton no its not ... but if you did update it to pass the url to determine the page requested instead of using php ...  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^api/ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/router.php?url=$1` then you are preserving the Query ... I always like to add it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `require_once`, try `file_get_contents`:

```
file_get_contents ((stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://'). "{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/herp/derp.php?" . http_build_query($query));
```

Be carefull with [SERVER_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297421/2905135).

**EDIT**

For the records, if you need to work with ANY method (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc.) or page infomation like cookies, you can use [streams](http://php.net/manual/es/function.stream-context-create.php) as a built-in (quicker?) alternative to cURL and PECL. In this example:

```
$params = array(
   'http' => array(
      'method' => 'GET',
      'content' => http_build_query($query)
   )
);

$context = stream_context_create($params);

file_get_contents (
   (stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://'). "{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/herp/derp.php", 
   false, 
   $context
);
```

Comment: While that'd sort of work it's doubling the number of requests (and would not preserve any headers or data from the original url - i.e. no session persistence, cookie info or POST data), overall it's not a good idea to use this kind of approach

Comment: It wouldn't work at all for the POST, PUT, or DELETE methods. If I wanted to do it that way, I would just use cURL. But again @Edakos, no additional requests is a requirement for this question.

Comment: _this answer_ works for any method? You don't address doubling requests =)