# Get domain name without port using HTTP_HOST

Tags: php

When I check the logs there are a few rare occasions where for some visitors(bot I think) the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is returning: www.domain.co.uk:80

What is the correct way to get only the domain name without any ports?

Should I be doing it this way instead:

```
$url_components = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$domain = $url_components['host'];
```

The strange thing is that I cant replicate this behavior it only appears in the logs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case **`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`** is your friend.

Comment: Oh I was thinking that HTTP_HOST was more reliable obviously wrong after reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2297421/560287

Comment: Both of them has their own purpose of strength.

Comment: This will not work if you have server names aliases.
Ex (nginx) : server { server_name new.exemple.com www.exemple.com; ... }
If you request for http://www.exemple.com/foo :
In this case $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is www.exemple.com and $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is new.exemple.com