# Easy IIS 7.5 url rewrite rule (from non-www to www) gives redirect loop error in browser

Tags: url, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

This seems like it should be such a 101-level question but I cannot get it to work.

I very simply need to set up a url rewrite rule that redirects mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com. That's it. But no matter how I go at it, I get a URL redirect error in my browser.

Below are a few different rule definitions I have tried, one-by-one. As far as I can tell, any should work. But none have. I would be incredibly grateful for any insight.

```
<rule name="non-www to www" enabled="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www.mydomain.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="non-www to www" enabled="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
</rule>

<rule name="non-www to www" enabled="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS, it's built in as a canonical host redirect.  See below to 301 redirect any request from http://example.com to http://www.example.com

```
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is meant to be "built in" here, but this rule, too, results in a redirect loop error for me.

Comment: I just mean that there's a wizard for it in IIS under the URL Rewrite module.  Click to add a new rule, and a canonical redirect is one of the options.  I'm certain what I have above is correct (I pulled it from one of my websites).  If you're seeing a redirect loop, then I'd guess that your browser is caching the 301 redirect.  I'd clear browser cache, close your browser, and retest.

Comment: Oh, I see. I actually don't really use the rewrite GUI much (maybe I should, if my hand-edits don't work!). Really appreciate your clarification, but I've been clearing browsing data every time and same result. Just doublechecked to be sure.

Any ideas what else could be going on? This particular site runs a bunch of hand-rolled ColdFusion code that I'm 99% sure contains no redirects (Application.cfm shows nothing suspect), as well as a WordPress multi-site install (but that's another directory level down from the root where I'm testing this).

Comment: oh and: I have zero other rules in place here at the root directory of this site.

Comment: Smells like something other than the IIS URLRewrite then to me.  Have you tested without the rewrite rule in the web.config?  If you still see any redirection there, then something else is at play.

Comment: I have. The page loads as expected, with browser url bar showing the non-www address.

Comment: What about when you go to the www address without the rewrite rule?  Does it redirect back to the non-www?

Comment: No; it remains as the www address, and loads normally. (On edit: just used the built-in GUI tool I hadn't known existed in order to create my rule; same result.)

Comment: Hmm.  My money's on something to do with Wordpress overwriting the HTTP_HOST server variable.  Are http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wrong-http_host-causes-infinite-redirect or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name relevant?

Comment: ! Maybe. Echoing HTTP_HOST from a PHP file at the site root gives me non-www. I'm trying to go digging now for where that might be getting set... (that question is 5 years old and the canonical.php file mentioned doesn't exist anymore in WP. but this seems like a fantastic lead.)

Comment: That's your answer then.  If the HTTP_HOST is always the non-www version, then that would result in an infinite loop with the code above.  I'm out for the night.  Good luck chasing it down.

Comment: Lord. This is incredibly embarrassing, but I requested my HTTP_HOST output test file *from* the non-www address. Requesting it from the www address shows me the www address as expected—so I'm back to being stumped.

Comment: I still have no clarity on my problem but I'm going to accept this answer because it seems like the rule given above SHOULD work on most server environments, and will probably work for anyone who isn't me. Thanks Ryan.