# PHP Change Root path depending on localhost vs server

Tags: php

Using PHP, I would like to have a simple config.php file that enables me to check whether I am on localhost vs mydomain.com.

For example, on 'localhost':

```
$path = '/'
```

But when I upload to my server ('mydomain.com'), I'd like to have the path be:

```
$path = '/testing/
```

I'd like to be able to check whether I am developing locally vs when the site is uploaded to my ftp.

Comment: Good idea!  And what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your current running server using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`:

```
$default_path = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') ? '/' : '/testing/';
```

There are plenty of other variables in the `$_SERVER` superglobal array, if you want to use another one you should debug it and find whichever one you want (I'm on Amazon servers and I've got tons of Amazon specific variables to choose from too):

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SERVER); exit;
```

`SERVER_NAME` is more reliable than others like `HTTP_HOST`, see [this article for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297421/2812842).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably check using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.  On localhost, this would return `127.0.0.1`:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1') {
    $path = '/';
} else {
    $path = '/testing/;
}
```

It is not 100% reliable, but works for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I use to have this line in my config files for that purpose

```
$isLocal=($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="127.0.0.1" );
```