# PHP get the user agent request URL

Tags: php, apache, url

**Background**

I have a little site that has been setup for our marketing team, it is configured on the same server as our core site. The site has been setup as `marketing.lan` in `Apache`. We have configured things so that any request made to our core site via the `/marketing` url load the `marketing.lan` pages. Example:

> https://www.coresite.com/marketing/test.php

will point to the `test.php` script on the `marketing.lan` site. No redirection done, the browser URL will still be

> www.coresite.com/marketing/test.php.

Apache is doing this by setting the host to marketing.lan for all request made via the 'www.coresite.com/marketing/' URL.

**Problem**

The problem is this, when I try and get the URL the page was accessed via using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` I get `marketing.lan/test.php` not `www.coresite.com/marketing/test.php`, even with the browser showing the correct URL.

**Question**
Is it possible to get the actual 'URL the script was accessed by? Or is this hidden by Apache? How would I do that.

Comment: The value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is coming from the config of the host, not from the request. `that any request mate to our core site via the /marketing url load the marketing.lan pages.` How is it done? You can add some additional info to that request.

Comment: try to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: I had a chat with the system admin, they have configured Apache to change the host to marketing.lan for nay requests that come in from the coresite.com/marketing.

Comment: Jay, The REQUEST_URI will only return the request bit of the URL not the domain.

Comment: @Cheery — No, `HTTP_HOST` reflects the contents of the `Host:` request header sent by the client ([See this answer, for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2297421/1679849)). You're possibly thinking of `SERVER_NAME`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage it does not really matter, because server should have this in the config to answer on the request with that host. Moreover, by the link, `after checking the answer of Pekka on your question which contains a link to bobince's answer that PHP would always return HTTP_HOST's value for SERVER_NAME` May be it is fixed, but the host that corresponds to host: gets response. Or the first in config, but I do not think this is a case.

Comment: @Cheery — often they're the same (and `SERVER_NAME` may not even be set). But it *does* matter where this information comes from. If you lead people into believing that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` contains trusted information provided by the server itself, then they will be liable to expose themselves to cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage don't you think that that case is a problem of server configuration? Compared to that the info in php will be the smallest of all the evil.

Answer (score 1):

#### My Understanding:

1. Both the sites are in the **same server** (presumably, a Linux machine)
2. `www.coresite.com` has a `DocumentRoot` something *like* `/var/www/coresite.com/`
3. `marketing.lan` has a `DocumentRoot` something *like* `/var/www/marketing.lan/`
4. You now want `marketing.lan` as a sub-site of `www.coresite.com` such that  **http://www.coresite.com/marketing/** shows the contents of **http://marketing.lan/**

---

#### How to do this

There is no need to modify their individual apache configuration; just create a `symlink`.

```
ln -s /var/www/marketing.lan /var/www/coresite.com/marketing
```

This will answer your **question**:

If your `test.php` has a line `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

- Going to the url `http://www.coresite.com/marketing/test.php` will show

  **`www.coresite.com/marketing/test.php`**
- Going to the url `http://marketing.lan/test.php` will show

  **`marketing.lan/test.php`**