# Title Tag depend on Domain Name

Tags: dns

I have two domain name,
DomainA and DomainB
When visitor call with DomainA,
Site Title Tag, Meta tag are change depend on DomainA keywords and also DomainB.
How do I do that with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You could check against the `$_SERVER` superglobal variable to find out what was sent in the request headers, specifically in this case `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. Based on this, you could in theory then assign anything dynamically based on this information.

You can read more about `$_SERVER` in [php's documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), and I'd recommend having a look at [this beautifully detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name), in terms of choosing which to rely on.