# local hostname identification messed up when `host:` header is modified.

Tags: php, apache, server, environment-variables

I created a simple php script with the following contents:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then I executed it on the server normally as a URL (example: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/whatever.php) and received information about what's installed, with php, etc.

Next, I used an advanced tool (opera dragonfly) and requested the same URL again, with the `host` HTTP request header changed from `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to a random word. I'll call the new value `word`.

The same page appears, but what I find is that the SCRIPT_URL environment variable value is http://word/whatever.php instead of `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/whatever.php` and HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME are both set to `word`.

Why can't one environment variable value be the domain part of the url someone types in (like `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`) and another one be the value of the http `host:` header? and how do I fix this?

I'm using apache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name