# PHP if statement not working as expected with filter_var

Tags: php, forms, filter-var, filter-validate-email

I have a form which posts variables through to a PHP processing script.

Before the processing script begins I would like to sanitize the posted variables:

```
$Contact_Name = filter_var($_POST['contactName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$Company = filter_var($_POST['company'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$Telephone = filter_var($_POST['telephone'],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

So far. So good.

But sanitizing and validating the email is a real pain.

```
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Sanitised_Email = filter_var($Email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$Email_is_valid = filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

If `$Sanitised_Email` isn't the same as `$Email`, I want to go back to the form page:

```
if ($Sanitised_Email != $Email) {
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/form.php');
}
```

If `$Email_is_valid` is `false`, I want to go back to the form page:

```
if ($Email_is_valid == FALSE) {
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/form.php');
}
```

Neither of these two `if` statements work when I enter an email which is both invalid and in need of sanitisation such as:

```
i.am.(totally)invalid@asanemailaddress
```

What am I doing wrong? Have I messed up my syntax somewhere?

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you should consider using [`!==` instead of `!=`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Why do you need to sanitize instead of just checking if the supplied address is valid?

Comment: One other note:  consider passing an error message back to the form rather than a plain-jane re-direct (thus likely leaving the user wondering why the form didn't submit).  You could improve your current method with a simple url parameter that triggers an error display on the form, for example.

Comment: Yes, I agree with passing an error message back to the form. Haven't got to that bit yet.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `if` that's "not working"?  'cause it works for me: http://codepad.org/qf3NIr0i

Comment: @PeeHaa, please acknowledge that I am learning how `filter_var` works.

Comment: Do you want to check wether the sanitized email is valid after its been cleaned? Or do you really want to run both functions on the user input email?

Comment: I want to check if the sanitized version of the email is the same as the user input email. Then I want to check if the user input email is valid.

Comment: After looking @RocketHazmat is it possible your "HTTP_HOST" is not returning anything? I've had that not be populated (or populated incorrectly) as a server variable before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name

Comment: When I echo the variables on the form processing page, `$Sanitized_Email` is not the same as `$Email` and `$Email_is_valid` shows up as `false`. So everything appears to be working. But it isn't. That's why I suspect I might have a syntax error, somewhere.

Comment: @Rounin: If you had a syntax error, you'd see a fatal error.  Either on the page, or in your server logs.  Also, try to replace the `header()` call with an `echo` to see if it's working.  Finally, try to add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to enable error reporting (you can also set this in php.ini).

Comment: is the code you mentioned at the top of the PHP page and are you sure you have not already sent output before trying to send header information.

Comment: That's an excellent point to raise @Dave, but it's the one thing that I did know to take account of when using `header(Location: ');`. What I didn't know was that if `header(Location: ');` comes before the end of the script, it must be followed by `exit();` as Daniel MK pointed out in his answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax seems good. I think your problem is that you are not ending your script after setting header. Change it to:

```
if (condition) {
        header('Location: www.example.com');
        exit();
}
```

Learn how to debug your code, you can simply echo something to know if you are entering a structure or not. A good practice is also to create a function to redirect pages, it's quick, clean and save some lines:

```
function redirect($page){
        header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/$page.php");
        exit();
}
```

Comment: That's a priceless answer, @Daniel MK - thank you so much! The problem, as you correctly identified was that I wasn't ending the script with `exit();` after setting the header. (I've used `header('Location: ');` several times before, but only ever at the end of scripts, so I've never been aware that this is necessary.) Setting up a `redirect(page);` function is a great idea and using `echo` statements to verify whether conditions are being followed properly is a very smart time-saver. Thank you for all your tips. If I could give you extra points, I would.

Comment: I'm glad I've helped you, you're welcome, thanks for your nice words =)