# make codeigniter guess $baseurl the correct way

Tags: php, apache, nginx, codeigniter-3

On my server i'm using nginx on port `8081` and apache on port `80` as an internal proxy to nginx.

And i have multiple domains `.org,.com,.net`

When i leave the `$base_url` empty in the config code igniter tries to guess the right base url , it shows that the base url is `localhost:8081` instead of `domain.org` or `domain.com`

When i set it manually:

`$base_url="domain.com";`

It doesn't work when i open the other domains like `domain.org` for example because the `$base_url` is still on the `.com` domain .

Is there any way to make code igniter smarter guessing the right `$base_url` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP\_HOST vs. SERVER\_NAME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Charlotte for the tip.

After some search on the `HTTP_HOST` server variable i discovered that `apache` is passing the `HTTP_HOST` to nginx as `localhost:8081`.

I use reverse proxy in apache to make the proxy behavior:

`ProxyPass  / http://localhost:8081/`
`ProxyPassReverse  / http://localhost:8081/`

I searched the [Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) of apache and found a directive called `ProxyPreserveHost`

> When enabled, this option will pass the Host: line from the incoming request to the proxied host, instead of the hostname specified in the ProxyPass line.

i enabled it by adding this line:

`ProxyPreserveHost On`

And it worked , now codeigniter can read `HTTP_HOST` right and make the `$base_url` right.

Answer (score 0):

sett base_url  in `config.php` .
like this 
`$config['base_url'] = 'actual url'` 
or 
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';`