# WAMP virtual host contains no domain

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I'm using WAMP, with a virtual host.  The problem is that when I'm on my virtual host,

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

contains only a "/" when I'm on the index; it doesn't contain the domain name. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `REQUEST_URI` is not supposed to contain the host, only the part after the host and before the query string. Use:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

Or:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

`HTTP_HOST` is the one that was specified in the request header (the actual host being visited). `SERVER_NAME` is the one that is set up as the `ServerName` on the virtual host. Not always the same as each other if coming in on a `ServerAlias`.

References:

- [PHP: Predefined Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
- [HTTP_HOST vs. SERVER_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name)