# Why this $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] code in PHP is giving me error?

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to programming, and I decided to try PHP.
I am trying to set the `variable $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]`.
Unfortunately, I'm getting some errors.

The code is copied from [this Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVJ0anq8yLA&list=PLillGF-Rfqbap2IB6ZS4BBBcYPagAjpjn&index=10), so it is supposed to be correct.

```
$server = [
         'Host Server Name' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
         'Host Header' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
         'Server Software' => $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],
         'Document Root' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],
         'Current Page' => $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
         'Script Name' => $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],
         'Absolute Path' => $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
];


//print_r($server);

// Create Client Array
$client = [
    'Client System info' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    'Client IP' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    'Remote Port' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']
];
```

**The error:**

```
Notice: Undefined variable:** server in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpsandbox\website2\server-info.php on line 7

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpsandbox\website2\server-info.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpsandbox\website2\server-info.php on line 7
```

Thanks to anyone for the support!

Comment: Your question title does not match the error message

Comment: Can you show your full code? It's not balking at `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, it's balking because `$server` is not defined when you try to use it on line 7, which usually happens when it's defined inside an if block

Comment: sorry for the title, I actually do not know the problem.
I edited the full code, which is copied by the teacher to be honest.

Comment: Try setting the server name as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297421/5779083, if @aynber s solution doesn't work.

Comment: Please show the first 10 lines of `server-info.php`

Comment: @aynber this is the full code as copied from the tutorial

Comment: Line 7 does not reference `$server`, nor have an operand (math), so the error is not in this code.

Comment: @aynber I guess  Tom solution is correct, even if I have no idea how to apply. Thanks a lot for the support