# Dynamically get page link based on breadcrumb level

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to create a breadcrumb menu via PHP and have the following so far:

```
<?php

// 1. Get URL
$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$address = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// 2. Strip extras
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
    echo "<a href=".$address.">"."<span class='crumbMenu'>".$crumb."</span></a>";
}

?>
```

Let's say I have the following page hierarchy: `Products > Products Level 2 > Products Level 3`

The above code will spit out:

```
Products
Products Level 2
Products Level 3
```

Which is correct. However, the links are not.

After reading up on [HTTP_HOST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/what-is-the-difference-between-http-host-and-server-name-in-php), I'm certain my approach is wrong, but unsure on what other approach I can take to dynamically get each crumb items link?

**Links I am getting:**

`localhost:8080`

**Links I am expecting:**

- **Products**: `/products`
- **Products Level 2**: `/products/products-level-2`
- **Products Level 3**: `/products/products-level-2/products-level-3`

Comment: What links are you getting. Can we get some examples.

Comment: You have the parts of the URL path already (in $crumbs) - you just need to assemble them correctly again. To correctly link to the second path segment in `/foo/bar`, you of course need to not link to `/bar` only, but you need to keep the previous segments as “prefixes”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten about adding routes to `$address` variable, so all your breadcrumbs point to base server address. Try the following:

```
<?php

// 1. Get URL
$crumbs = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$address = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// 2. Strip extras
$build = $address.'/products';
foreach($crumbs as $crumb){
    if(in_array($crumb, [$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'products'])) {
        continue;
    }
    $build .= '/'.$crumb;
    $crumb = ucfirst(str_replace(array(".php","_"),array(""," "),$crumb) . ' ');
    echo "<a href=".$address.$build.">"."<span class='crumbMenu'>".$crumb."</span></a>";
}

?>
```

Comment: better than my  :D

Comment: Perfect! has the correct links showing up now. Would you happen to know why my for loop is spitting out additional links? I.e. I expect it to only display three links in inspect mode, but it's show five (`localhost:8080` , `/products` , `/products/products-level-2/` , `/products/products-level-2/products-level-3` and `/products/products-level-2/products-level-3` again? You've already answered the original question so happy to resolve this thread if otherwise

Comment: I have updated my answer, it's not ideal solution but will work in your case.

Comment: Ah, I see the approach, but looking for a more dynamic way to approach this. I'm marking this complete since you've already solved my original question, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to ready your echo which is not helpful. I created small function which should do what you have asked for. Feel free to modify it for your needs.

```
$crumbs = "/x/y/z";
$address = "localhost:8080";

$crumbs = explode('/', $crumbs);
$end = '';
$href = '';
foreach ($crumbs as $crumb) {
    $crumb = str_replace('.php', '', $crumb);
    $end .= $crumb . ' ';
    $href .= $crumb . '/';
}

echo("HREF => " . $href);
echo("\n");
echo("TITLE => " . $end);
```