# PHP get domain name

Tags: php, domain-name

I want to get the domain name for where the script is running. How can that be done with PHP?
I see that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` as well as `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` contain this information.
Will that variable always work and should I use one over the other?

Thank you.

Comment: That does answer part of my question about using SERVER_NAME over the other, but is this the right way to do this in PHP? (is the other part) Thank you.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Similar question has been asked in stackoverflow before.

See here: [PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] vs. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], am I understanding the man pages correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459739/php-serverhttp-host-vs-serverserver-name-am-i-understanding-the-man)

Also see this article: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host

> Recommended using HTTP_HOST, and
>   falling back on SERVER_NAME only if
>   HTTP_HOST was not set. He said that
>   SERVER_NAME could be unreliable on the
>   server for a variety of reasons,
>   including:
>
> - no DNS support
> - misconfigured
> - behind load balancing software
>
> *Source*:
>   *http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-4388.html*

Comment: HTTP_HOST seems right to me. SERVER_NAME worked fine until we started using Docker, then just gave us "localhost". Just note that HTTP_HOST will give you the sub-domain too.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question, these should work as long as:

- Your HTTP server passes these values along to PHP (I don't know any that don't)
- You're **not** accessing the script via command line (CLI)

But, if I remember correctly, these values can be faked to an extent, so it's best not to rely on them.

My personal preference is to [set the domain name as an environment variable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) in the apache2 virtual host:

```
# Virtual host
setEnv DOMAIN_NAME example.com
```

And [read it in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php):

```php
// PHP
echo getenv(DOMAIN_NAME);
```

This, however, isn't applicable in all circumstances.