# How can an embedded website tell who is embedding it?

Tags: php, html, embed

I have a simple HTML website `www.some_website.com`.
On the `index.html` page, I am embedding an external php script called `embedded_site.php` from an external source.

I am using the `<embed>` tag to embed the php script into the website like so.

```
<body>
  <div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">  
      <embed type="text/html" src="https://myotherwebsite.com/embedded_site.php">
  </div>
</body>
```

**How can the `embedded_site.php` detect which site is embedding it?**

```
+---------------------------------+
|      www.some_website.com       |
|   +-------------------------+   |
|   | embedded_site.php       |   |
|   | detected: embedded by   |   |
|   | some_website.com!       |   |
|   +-------------------------+   |
|                                 |
+---------------------------------+
```

I have tried in `embedded_site.php`:

```
<?php echo($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);?>
```

but that gives me the IP of the client, not the *embedding* site `www.some_website.com`.

**Intended Purpose**

If the `embedded_site.php` script is embedded on the wrong site, it needs to be able to detect that and disable itself.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404811/php-get-domain-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404811/php-get-domain-name).

Comment: That link is not related at all.

Comment: Are you looking for: gethostname(); 

Or, an option that also works before PHP 5.3 php_uname('n');  http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php

Comment: @Mike that only returns the name of the server, not the public IP

Comment: Sorry misreaded the question

Answer (score 1):

what about this:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

instead of

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Comment: That would return "/php/embedded_link.php" but I need the url of the website that is embedding the page