# Can I use the server path for <img>?

Tags: php, html

I have two domains sitting on a single server, and I want to use images from domain A, on domain B.

However, I don't want users of domain B to know that the images are being pulled from domain A.

So insetad of putting:

```
<img src = "http://DOMAIN A/image.jpg">
```

I'd prefer to do something like:

```
<img src = "path/on/server/image.jpg">
```

...but I that doesn't work - I definitely have the correct path:

```
/home/username/public_html/images/image.jpg
```

as perform a file_exists on the image first with that path.

As an alternative, I've tried using:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,...">
```

But there are alot of images and this method is super slow.

Comment: Relative path (2nd attempt) should work, you only need the correct path

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717249/get-current-domain

Comment: I definitely have the correct path: /home/username/public_html/images/image.flv as perform a file_exists on the image first, but for it just won't show the image.

Comment: You cannot do this on the client side... see the answers below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible as the image tag is executed by the client. You may add some kind of symlinks in the web server directory of B to point to the files of A.

Or use apache alias option to locate the files (like the cgi-bin does):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Answer (score 1):

You can use a redirect on the server, e.g. via mod_rewrite.
Just redirect a special folder from server A to server B.

Try something like (on server A, inside a .htaccess file if you´re on an Apache web server):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/img/(.+)  http://server-b.com/img/$1  [R,L]
```

Then you can point to server A in the HTML, but the server redirects this to server B behind the scenes.

Or check the [Apache documentation of rewriting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

No. HTTP clients have no access to the file system of the computer the HTTP server is running on.

If you want to hide the domain where the image is hosted, then you have to provide a different URL (on a different domain) to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can this way,

`http://serverip/~sitefolder/`**imagesfolder/images.jpg**

but @Tobiask method is better than this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do use relative url paths:

if your html document is located at

```
/home/username/public_html/index.html
```

use

```
<img src="images/image.jpg" />
```

if it is on a different user account, and yours is located at http://host.com/~username/index.html you can use

```
<img src="../~otherusername/images/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: I think this won´t work on most servers that are secure enough to disallow the access to other user folders.

Comment: This relies on there public html folder being exposed at "~username". It looked as if that was the case. However it may still not be a correct solution..

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use

ln -s path/on/server/image.jpg image.jpg

Works on my default apache setup.