# PHP get base link current site

Tags: php, hyperlink, project, root

I have a php-project which is uploaded to a website, my index.php is located at the root of my project which is made like this: http://www.website.com/projectroot . Is there any way to get the link of my projectroot in php from any subdirectory or phpscript? If http://website.com would be my project root, it should return website.com.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717249/get-current-domain

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirley sure what you're asking for, but most people use

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
```

If this isn't what you're after, then you may be better off creating a subdomain or vhost in your httpd file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global variable in php: `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. 
Example how you can use that:
`<a href = "<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>"> Link to Main Site</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo "Your Website Root : " . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```