# “&” being replaced by "&amp; in php include

Tags: php, regex, url, hyperlink

I have a php page which get response from another page as shown:

```
while($response!=200)
{
$response = include 'xyz.php?one='.$one.'&two='.$two.'&three='.$three.'';
}
```

But my link always get's something like:

```
domainname.com/xyz.php?one=content&amp;two=content&amp;three=content
```

And due to `&` getting replaced by `&amp;` I am getting the page not found issue.

I have tried using `%26` and directly putting `&amp;` instead of `&`, all in vain.

Is there any other simple solution besides using string replace function of PHP to remove `&amp;` and replace it with `&`

Comment: Even with that replacement, you shouldn't get a page not found. The page name is only the part up to `?`, everything after that is URL parameters.

Comment: I would avoid using `include()` in this case, looks like you want to get the response from an HTTP(s) request. You could use `file_get_contents('http://example.com/?one=....');`
For `include()`, look at [Example 3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). Also, not sure your `$response` would ever be 200...

Comment: @MariosHadjimichael, I still get the Warning: file_get_contents(Path) failed to open stream.

Comment: @Barmar, I get the Warning: include(Path) failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Path. Here xyz.php is a local file.

Comment: You can't use URL parameters when accessing a local file, they only make sense when accessing a URL through a webserver.

Comment: Yes, as @Barmar said, you will need to use the Full URL with `file_get_contents()`. There are ways to [figure it out based on the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717249/get-current-domain) if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
$response = html_entity_decode($response)
```

Comment: His problem isn't with the response, it's with the URL he's trying to get the response from.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test based on the code you sent and I don't have a problem.  That suggests you have something auto-magical going on in your *.ini file (magic quotes, maybe... ugh...).  Try to create the string simply as a variable to remove it from the filename context and echo it out to be sure it's right, then use the variable with your `include`.

```
$one = 'abc';
$two = 'def';
$three = "ghi";
$file= 'xyz.php?one='.$one.'&two='.$two.'&three='.$three;
echo "\n\n".$file;
$response = include $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use URL parameters when accessing a local file, they have to go through the webserver. Try:

```
$response = file_get_contents("http://localhost/path/to/xyz.php?one='.$one.'&two='.$two.'&three='.$three);
```

Comment: xyz.php is a local file itself. In that file I am returning a value using a REST API. That xyz.php is returning value correctly, as I manually ran it in my localhost.

Comment: You can't use URL parameters when accessing a local file.

Comment: Won't putting http://localhost cause a problem when I upload the files for hosting?

Comment: Aren't you uploading `xyz.php` as well?

Comment: Yes, I am, that is why I am asking.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be a problem, since `localhost` will access the hosting server when you upload it.