# Display different text based on domain extension

Tags: php

Apologize if this has already been asked and answered; did a quick search, but, not exactly sure how to word it/what exactly to search for.

I have to web addresses pointing to one site/file(s). One ends in *.net* [domain.net] and the other ends in *.org* [domian.org].

Using PHP; I want to put at least the "*.net*" and/or "*.org*" part of the URL into a variable to determine what text is displayed.

Something to the effect of:

```
$domainExt = 'net';
```

For domain ending with .net; as an example.

Thanks for any help, tips, etc.

Comment: Please provide some more code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717249/get-current-domain)

Comment: So you want to split/explode on dot to get the top level domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the extension

```
$host = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST');
$domainExt = pathinfo($host, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Then switch through the extension

```
switch($domainExt){
    case "net":
        $var = "yada";
        break;

    case "org":
        $var = "yada yada";
        break;
}
```

You can apply this example to fit your needs

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment information.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

or

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
<?php
$host =  filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST');
$domainExt = substr(strrchr($host, "."), 1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just explode the current HTTP_HOST at the period.

```
$ext = explode( '.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );

if( $ext == 'org' ){
    echo 'This is .org';    
} else {
    echo 'This is .net';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parse_url() function to get the domain extention.

Example below:

```
 $url = 'http://www.example.com/site';
    echo end(explode(".", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST))); 
// output "com"
```

Dynamically get the domain extension like below way.

```
$url =  'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; 
echo end(explode(".", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST))); 
// output "com"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to separate the website on different folder for .net and .org and use Virtual Host to route the domain names on their respective folders.

sorry for my English but i hope you get the point.

[If you are using apache then google search can help you](https://www.google.com.ph/search?ei=jNagWqbMKIqG8wWW2aWgDg&q=apache%20virtual%20host&oq=apache%20virtual%20host&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i67k1j0i7i30k1j0i67k1j0i7i30k1l4j0l2.83648.84252.0.84458.6.6.0.0.0.0.139.554.2j3.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.4.454....0.JK-fCNxg0fA)