# Different content in same php

Tags: php

How do we display different content in a different domain on the same website?

```
example
domain.com content show this in body
*hello you are vising domain.com*

domain.net content show this in body
*hello you are vising domain.net*
```

[.com content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvefD.jpg) and
[.net content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neTpP.jpg)

But `domain.net` and `domain.com` is the same website in the same server. `domain.net` is a mirror from `domain.com`.
Do I need to use `php if condition blablabla`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717249/get-current-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Use the global variable $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']==='domain.com') { ?>
here is the contents of domain.com
<?php else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']==='domain.net') { ?>
here is the contents of domain.net
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP: [Get current domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717249/get-current-domain)

In JavaScript: [Get current domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717249/get-current-domain)

Then you can do some if/else statements in either PHP or JavaScript and display your content accordingly.

regards,

Umar Abdullah