# email domain matches current domain

Tags: php, server

I have an application that will run on other domains. The application needs to check if an email address matches the domain of the site running the application.

So, if email = fred@example.com ,

- if application is running on example.com , return true
- if application is running on anything.example.com, return true
- if application is running on domain.com, return false

I understand that the $_SERVER variables might be incorrect due to spoofing. So what is the best way for the server running the application to get the server's domain name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717249/get-current-domain)

Comment: No, because the SERVER variables listed in there are not secure, and not always available.  See one of the answers in that link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301646/1466973 .

Comment: I guess the question is more towards this in that case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459739/php-serverhttp-host-vs-serverserver-name-am-i-understanding-the-ma I wouldn't trust `HTTP_*` values.