# CodeIgniter - relative href links broken

Tags: codeigniter, routes, url-rewriting

I recently had to move a CodeIgniter based website from the web root of:

```
/var/www/vhosts/dev/
```

to:

```
/var/www/vhosts/dev/site1/
```

The problem I am encountering is that I need the web root to still remain accessible from the domain: www.devdomain.com

All relative links now are broken since they obviously were referring to the web root.
Is there a rewrite rule or something at the top-level I can use that will automatically add the `site1/` to all relative based links?

So, what would have normally been;

```
<a href="/enrollment">Enrollment</a>
https://www.devdomain.com/enrollment
```

Now needs to become;

```
<a href="/enrollment">Enrollment</a>
https://www.devdomain.com/site1/enrollment
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $config['base_url'] fix Nikola mentions would work if you used, in your links, the

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/enrollment">Enrollment</a>
```

Since apparently you don't want to go through the code the problem isn't in Codeigniter but in the server (?). Maybe a RewriteRule in the .htaccess file can help you (if you're on Apache).

I can't comment other answers since my rep level is low, otherwise I would've simply commented on Nikola's answer.

EDIT: I just figured this out. You have to remove the initial "/" from the href attributes! It is going to the root of the webserver, it is being a relative link but not the way you think. If you remove the "/" the link will go to a file on the same directory level of your file (in this case the Codeigniter installation). Sorry but you'll have to go through your whole code.

Additionally I would recommend for you to use site_url() to link between controllers inside Codeigniter, helps with this kind of situations and a lot others.

SECOND EDIT: It's not site_url() but base_url(), sorry for the confusion. Just corrected the code.

Comment: I tried adding this to my rewrite rule, but it didn't appear to work.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site1/index.php?/$1 [L]
And my RewriteBase is now /site1/
Is that the correct approach?

Comment: I will try that and see how it works. That makes perfect sense! Let me go give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: That definitely seemed to resolve the issue with the links. When I tried to apply that same logic to the SRC paths for css, no styles loaded. Does that make sense?

Comment: But CSS files are referenced by href, not src: <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> You can also use the base_url() method in Codeigniter to prepend to the URL.

Comment: Thank you, jakobhans. I really appreciate your help with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here on the topic of `base_url()` vs `site_url()` and why you use one over the other.

[How to set proper codeigniter base url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url/11801195#11801195)

For generating links to CodeIgniter generated pages, `site_url()` is in fact the correct function. Additionally, passing the url as the argument to the function as a string makes generating urls cleaner. Observe:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/enrollment">Enrollment</a>
```

vs:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('enrollment'); ?>">Enrollment</a>
```

or even:

```
<?php echo anchor('enrollment', 'Enrollment'); ?>
```

Comment: Brendon, thank you also for that very insightful addition to this post. That's very helpful.