# Bootstrap cannot access using Code Igniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I paste bootstrap folder inside my CodeIgniter folder and added it to my config.php.

```
$config['bootstrap'] = 'bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

and call it to my php script(view).

```
$bootstrap = $this->config->item('bootstrap'); 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo "$base/$bootstrap";?>">
```

But still I getting a 404 error.

Comment: What's `$base`? You could use `base_url(config_item('bootstrap'))`

Comment: $base = $this->config->item('base_url'); ... this is my $base.

Comment: I have just tested it on a local install of CI3 and it worked. What is the URL to the stylesheet when you view the page source?

Comment: `echo base_url(config_item('bootstrap'));` worked for me, when I added `$config['bootstrap'] = 'bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.css';` to config.php

Comment: the URL is correct but when access it its 404 error, That is already my config.php setup.

Comment: but I access it when I paste it to my css folder.

Comment: Please check the fileaccess to the .css too

Comment: You have syntax error `href="<? echo "$base/$bootstrap";?>"> `. Use this `href="<? echo $base.'/'.$bootstrap;?>">  `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$base` is previously defined (usually with `base_url()` [**how to set base_url**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url)). Change this:

```
href="<? echo "$base/$bootstrap";?>"
```

To this:

```
href="<?php echo "$base/$bootstrap";?>"
```

Or alternatively, if you want to use short tags:

```
href="<?= "$base/$bootstrap";?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you **autoload the url helper**.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo "$base/$bootstrap";?>">
```

Replace With

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(config_item('bootstrap'));?>">
```

Also make sure **bootstrap-3.3.5-dist** folder is in **Main Directory**