# How to call sitemap.xml in codeigniter application

Tags: codeigniter, sitemap

i have added sitemap.xml file to my codeigniter project.

And i call it on my localhost like that : `http://localhost/demo/sitemap.xml`
it runs without any issue.

But when i run it on live server `http://example.com/demo/sitemap.xml`
it says 404 page not found.

What is issue ?

Comment: Please check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url This helped me solve the similar problem.

Comment: Maybe to exclude it from rewrite rule (I.E. `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt)`)?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add below things in your **config/routes.php** file

```
$route['sitemap\.xml'] = 'demo/sitemap'; // your navigation path i.e. your controller_name/function_name
```

Comment: Thanks, what will code for that function can you explain me ?

Comment: sorry, I am not getting you.. what you want to know ?