# How to set config_base url in config.php file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am beginner in `Codeigniter`.
I have downloaded the software and tried to configure it. How can I configure a base url to use in codeigniter?

Comment: `application/config/config.php` and set your base_url `$config['base_url']`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url

Comment: @Dipika You must search related question before asking question a new one. See the link added above by **Soliyappan**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should got to this file path

Codeigniter/applications/config/config.php

Search for this line that contains

```
$config['base_url'] = ""
```

Then your base_url should be

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://yoursite.com/"
```

If xampp, it should be

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/yoursite/"
```

And if wamp, it should be

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www/yoursite/"
```

Note that yoursite is the filename of the site folder you have in htdocs or www folder

When you make use of `<?php echo base_url(directory/file_name); ?>` In your views, it should output something like:

```
 "http://localhost/yoursite.com/directory/file_name"
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Base URL should be absolute, including the protocol:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://somesite.com/somedir/";
```

If using the URL helper, then `base_url()` will output the above string.

Passing arguments to `base_url()` or `site_url()` will result in the following assuming

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

Comment: This is the best and most complete reply since it is the unique one that mentions the URL helper

Answer (score 0):

Go to application/config , open config.php and put value in this variable

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Comment: Ya that's i Know.If i want to configure in localhost then what url I need to pass out??

Comment: http ://localhost/yourwebsitename

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Following solutions is detailed provided you have *setup* your *localhost*
on your *machine* successfully.

Both the points as mentioned above will work.
Like, you can set the **Base URL** value for your corresponding setting of *localhost* or you can set it to **EMPTY**.

1. Setting as Empty (*Simple and Elegant*)

   > $config['base_url'] = '';

The Codeigniter version 2.0.0.0 simply [autodetects](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/b563d76e574ba02df3fca9fe6ab21bf9be348c7b/system/core/Config.php#L68) the base_url of your current project.

But in CI version 3.0.0.0 it's **NOT** supported anymore. You have to explicitly declare you projects Base URL.

2. Configuring the path to your Project Directory. The following procedure is when you setup your localhost using **xampp** in **Windows** or using default *Apache's* configuration folder in **Linux** i.e *var/www/html/your_project_directory*.

   > $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_directory';
3. Using **nginx** configuration in **Linux** or **wamp** in **Windows**

   > $config['base_url'] = "http://www/your_project_directory/"

Answer (score 0):

if you are running your project in local-server like Xamp or wamp then you can set the base url like this
$config['base_url']=""; or you can also set $config['base_url']="http://host/yoursite"