# CodeIgniter redirect() not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

Below given is the `index()` of my Admin controller (only admin should access this section):

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $user = $this->session->user;
    if (!$user)
        $this->load->view('admin\login_form');
    else
        redirect('admin/dashboard'); // I tried redirect('dashboard'); too
}
```

If the user is logged in, it redirects to `localhost/store/localhost/store/index.php/dashboard`. i.e., it appends the whole url after my base url (which is `localhost/store`). I also tried `'refresh'` as the second parameter in `redirect()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with slash:

```
 redirect('/admin/dashboard')
```

Comment: I am not pro in codeigniter but this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url