# Codeigniter url route can not pust right url

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In this view, I want to post login data to controller but it didn't work and return this url: http://[::1]/ci/index.php/verifylogin

View:

```
 <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
 <label for="username">Username:</label>
 <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
 <br/>
 <label for="password">Password:</label>
 <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
```

Comment: if you using default URL mechanism , put `form_open('ControllerName/MethodName')`

Comment: i have tried, but its return http://[::1]/ci/index.php/verifylogin/index this url

Comment: have you setup `base_url` under config file?

Comment: No, base url is empty.

Comment: put your values there

Comment: ok, but what should i put here?

Comment: your local host base eg: url https://localhost/sitename.com/

Comment: If you working on local machine then `http://localhost/projectDirectory`

Comment: you should read that link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url

Comment: @jagad89 says right

Comment: thank you, it posted right way but give me error, i guess another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is about "base_url" settings, I set it $config['base_url'] = 'localhost:83/ci/';; and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code help u.

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('verifylogin')); ?>
```

verifylogin may be your method name so pass your controller name after.

```
ex. : base_url('controller_name/verifylogin')
```