# How to fix requested URL not found error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and I am trying to build a registration page using it. When I am calling a function in the controller the server returns "The requested URL /Users/actionRegister was not found on this server" error.

I changed the .htaccess file and rewrite_mode on apache modules was started.

```
<?php echo form_open('Users/actionRegister'); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" id="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group pull-right">
        <button type="submit" id="register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Could you please help me to fix this error?

Comment: is the `Users/actionRegister` route defined in `application/config/routes.php` yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can check if load the helper form on your controller, this should be like this:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

On you code `<?php echo form_open('Users/actionRegister'); ?>` the `Users/actionRegister` can be defined on routes.php (`this file is located under application/config`) for convenient access of your function. You can do that like this:

```
$route['register'] = 'Users/actionRegister';
```

**In order to call the defined function, you can now call `base_url().'register'` inside form_open function.**

Please read more about [Configuring base_url in CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url)

Before that, you must edit your `.htaccess` file in order to recognize your routes in CI.
Like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

We'll see if you get through this.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should refer to [CodeIgniter user_guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/search.html?q=naming&check_keywords=yes&area=default) to name your files correctly

create a controller (`application/controllers/Users.php`) and post some code in it:

```
<?php 
Class Users extends CI_Controller(){
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index(){
        echo '<code>users/index/</code> is called';
    }

    public function actionRegister(){
        if($_POST){
            var_dump($_POST);
            }else{
            echo 'direct access to this function is not allowed';
        }
    }
}
```

then use direct access to your url like this `localhost/codeigniter/users/actionregister/`