# How to Fix My Image Didn't Showing In My Page?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

My image didn't call, with the current path. How to fix it?
The folder data in out of folder application.

I'm using a framework `Codeigniter` with `Bootstrap`.

```
<center>
          <a href="../../data/images/buying.png" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="How to Buying in Store">
          <img class="img-flu rounded mb-4" src="../../data/images/buying.png" alt="" >
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set up this on application->config->config.php before using the base_url().

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8000/sitename';
```

In view

```
<center>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>data/images/buying.png" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="How to Buying in Store">
          <img class="img-flu rounded mb-4" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>data/images/buying.png" alt="" >
</center>
```

For more info about the proper setup or uses of base_url()

[How to set proper codeigniter base url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url)

Comment: Thanks for attention but i found the answer in first answer :D