# PHP: $_SERVER variables: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] vs $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTP_HOST vs. SERVER_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name)

What is the difference between `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` ??

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` gives the value of the server name as defined in host configuration (i.e for Apache the Apache `.conf` file).

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` gives you the domain name through which the current request is being fulfilled and is more directly related to the request.

`HTTP_HOST` is typically more useful in most applications in that it relates directly to the request, whereas `SERVER_NAME` could return whatever value is in the conf file and doesn't tell you anything about the request at all.

I will give you an example of how `HTTP_HOST` might differ from `SERVER_NAME`. Say you have an host defined in Apache with ServerName of `example.com`  and an IP address of `1.2.3.4`.

Let's look at two incoming request URLs and show the difference between these variables:

```
http://www.example.com
HTTP_HOST = www.example.com
SERVER_NAME = example.com

http://1.2.3.4
HTTP_HOST = 1.2.3.4
SERVER_NAME = example.com
```

So again, HTTP_HOST is tied more to the request, whereas SERVER_NAME is determined by server configuration.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] "gives you the domain name through which the current request is being fulfilled and it more related to the request." +1
THANKS!!!! 
And Thanks to people linking to the official doc, but too complicated for me ;)

Comment: @Mike, It's not just `SERVER_NAME` that depends on the server configuration. [`HTTP_HOST` also depends on it.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28889208/632951)

Answer (score 2):

`HTTP_HOST` is the `Host:` header sent by the client.  As a result, it might be a little less trustworthy.  `SERVER_NAME` is determined by your server's configuration<strike>, regardless of user input.</strike>

The difference in behavior is subtle.   Some good examples are demonstrated here: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host

[The docs explain this well](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> 'SERVER_NAME' The name of the server host under which the current script is executing. If the script is running on a virtual host, this will be the value defined for that virtual host.
>
> 'HTTP_HOST' Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. `SERVER_NAME` is determined by your server's configuration, and [can be made (indeed *that's* the default behavior) to depend](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28889208/632951) on user input.

Comment: A good example of the subtleties of HTTP_HOST versus SERVER_NAME is demonstrated here: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host

Comment: Yes it's the same one from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1459794/632951 . `SERVER_NAME` is determined by server's config, and can be made to depend on user input.

Comment: @Pacerier I think it's accurate to say it's the default behaviour of Apache. The source doesn't say anything other than Apache.

Answer (score 0):

**`HTTP_HOST`**

> Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.

**`SERVER_NAME`**

> The name of the server host under which the current script is executing. If the script is running on a virtual host, this will be the value defined for that virtual host.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Of course the output isn't the same........