# $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] both different than actual URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When accessing the URL **www.domain.com/test.php**, both `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` output the domain name without the **www.** prefix: `domain.com`

Why would that be this way ?

EDIT: as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772934), `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` could be different than the actual requested URL, however `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` should return the domain.

PHP version: 7.1 
Apache version : 2.2

.htaccess content is as follow (the interesting part is the top rewrite block)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN Force SSL for SAKURA
# RewriteしてもHTTPS環境変数を有効にする
SetEnvIf REDIRECT_HTTPS (.*) HTTPS=$1


# 常時HTTPS化(HTTPSが無効な場合リダイレクト)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-cron\.php$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END Force SSL for SAKURA

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And here is the content of test.php:

```
<?php 
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

echo  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Output is "domain.com" and "domain.com/test".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: $\_SERVER variables: $\_SERVER\['HTTP\_HOST'\] vs $\_SERVER\['SERVER\_NAME'\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772934/php-server-variables-serverhttp-host-vs-serverserver-name)

Comment: @Obsidian Age How that thread can be "possible duplicate" with issue above?

Comment: @Obsidian Thanks for the suggestion, but this question related to why these two variables are different, my question is why my URL is different than these variables (at least HTTP_HOST should be  the same for what I understand)

Answer (score 0):

Well that top interesting rewrite block you mentioned is removing the `www.` from the URL with a 301 redirect. So there's no way of a request getting to your PHP script with the `www.` intact, because any request including the `www.` is issued a 301 redirect and never gets to the PHP script. The browser is then re-issuing the request based on the 301 redirect, and now it gets to your script without the `www.`.

You can test this by commenting out that top block, clearing your browser cache (important - or using a different browser), and visiting the test page again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
the thing is we actually want this redirection to work, but right now when we call the page www.domain.com it stays in www.domain.com. As I didn't find any way to make this redirection work, I thought I could write a redirection in PHP instead but I am not able to detect if the requested URL starts with www or not (since $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] value is "domain.com"). I hope this is more clear.
EDIT: the htaccess redirection do work for http but not https