# Make website accessible only from specific domain

Tags: php

Is there any way (PHP) to make my website accessible only if opened from my domain ?

e.g if mydomain.com was navigated to, website should open, if it's any other domain the website should not open.

For whatever reason there's a lot of random domains pointing their A records to my server and I don't want my website opened if it's not through my domain.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "from my domain", can you make an example?

Comment: Wouldn't you be handling that at the server level, rather than in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP $\_SERVER\['HTTP\_HOST'\] vs. $\_SERVER\['SERVER\_NAME'\], am I understanding the man pages correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459739/php-serverhttp-host-vs-serverserver-name-am-i-understanding-the-ma)

Comment: The right solution for this is to configure Apache, or whatever web server you use. If you're seeing a lot of weird attention to your machine, I suggest you set up a solid firewall as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check whether the `Host:` header matches your domain and show an error if it doesn't.