# Taking the user back to the initial page after login?

Tags: php, html, get

I'm using PHP, I wanted to know if a user lands on a certain page, and they have to login or signup to be able to do actions like commenting or rating etc. I wanted to able to take the user back to that same page after they login.

I was thinking to use the PHP `get` function and pass the URL, I'm not sure that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably your login fields are in an html form. When you're constructing the form, put the current URI in a hidden input field, then you have the information available to you when you want to perform the redirect after the POST data has been submitted.

I don't typically use PHP without a framework, but here are some resources that will help you get this information:

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php

[How can I get the current page's full URL on a Windows/IIS server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189113/how-do-i-get-current-page-full-url-in-php)

Basically, it goes like this:

```
$current_url = "http://" .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

But if you are using `https`, you have to change that string accordingly.

Comment: Beware with HTTP_HOST, since it's generated from the client request and can be a entry point for XSS atacks http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to redirect them back to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. One thing to take into consideration is that the browser can choose not to send the Referer URL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably a little too late but...

```
$home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . 'index.php';
```

I also forgot you would put this after, this is what would actually take you back to the home page

```
header('Location: ' . $home_url);
```

Comment: Don't forget to `exit` or equivalent after sending `Location:` headers.