# Complete URL in php

Tags: php, url

How can we echo the complete url of the current page in PHP if the url is something like

```
http://www.abcd.in/emi-calc22.php#about
```

I have different tabs such as #about, #new on that page. I would like to identify the Div displayed on the page corresponding to the tabs with the help of the URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get current page full URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189113/how-do-i-get-current-page-full-url-in-php)

Comment: Also please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side

Comment: Those URL's are IIS/ASP specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the fragment part of URL through PHP.

Because it is not being sent to server hence you can not get it `#about`

Answer (score 2):

The fragments can only be accessed on the client side (javascript) this is because when you press an url with a # in it you don't actually make a new request to the server but your browser processes it.

If you really want to get the # part to the server you will have to use ajax or a redirect function in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP on the page then why not pass the tab id as a query string, this will force a page refresh but you will have access to the URL's query string value server side via $_GET or $_REQUEST.

e.g. `<a href="/samepage.php?tab=about">About Tab</a>`

This could then be accessed in PHP via `$_GET['tab']`, then just use a [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) or something to load the relevant div.

No need for complicated AJAX or javascript!!