# PHP $_GET[url] not working

Tags: php

HI im trying to develop a MVC pattern through a website , from the beginning I need to get url I tried like this

```
echo $url= $_GET['url'];
echo $url;
```

If i use a url like this http://localhost/autolink/index/sdsad  it wanna show "index/sdsad" but its not showing anything, what can be wrong on this? can be a version problem? coz used in a another machine it was working..

This is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: See this link for the help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189113/how-do-i-get-current-page-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 4):

If that url was working on another machine then you had some sort of rewrite rules in place.  You likely had something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^autolink/.* autolink.php/?url=$0 [QSA,PT]
```

This would make the index/sdsad get passed in as a url argument in the query string.

Your example works for me and implies that you either

1. Don't have mod_rewrite turned on
2. Don't have Allow Overrides turned on

Easiest way to check (assuming this is not a production server) is to edit the .htaccess file and put in something like "POOP" on the first line.  If you start getting 500 errors, then 1 and 2 above do not apply.

Comment: I added your comment to your original question.

Comment: 'RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]'

Comment: Im not geting any 500 error, rest of the things on that page working perfectly. only echo $url= $_GET['url']; not showing

Comment: Thank you very much its working now... I didnt do anything.. the problem on Browser. Thanks ALOT sberry

Comment: Now I can get url from  echo $url= $_GET['url']; but when I use  http://localhost/autolink/index/sdsad  index is not showing let say if i use othe than index then its working , http://localhost/autolink/notindex/sdsad  .. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I develope PHP projects with Visual Studio 2019 Community by using PHP Tools for Visual Studio 2019 and IIS. I got the same problem during testing MVC patern and instead $_GET['url'] which did't work started to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].