# How to reliably get the current URL in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get current page full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189113/how-do-i-get-current-page-full-url-in-php)

I want to do something like this:

```
if (current url is 'site.com/dir1')
    do something;
else if (current url is 'site.com')
    do something else;
```

What's a reliable way to find this out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. This should give you the URL that the visitor is using.

Answer (score 2):

You can synthesise it with:

```
'http' . (443 == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

For IIS you don't get `REQUEST_URI`:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1);
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the wrong duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="url"){}
```

Should do the trick.