# echo php self query

Tags: php, javascript

Iam using below line in my script tag, here is that line:

```
var url = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>";
```

The above line working fine and its redirecting to http://mysite.com , but I want it to redirect to http://mysite.com/shop/c/mycategoryname

where mycatgeoryname should be whatever the category-name it was in url, that I shud get..

can anyone pls..?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189113/how-do-i-get-current-page-full-url-in-php?

Comment: @JonathanSampson I like the rethoricness in your comment :)

Comment: From which page are you going to redirect to http://mysite.com/shop/c/mycategoryname

Comment: Let's see the rest of your JavaScript.

Comment: try `print_r($_SERVER);` in your php code, it shall give guide you achieving the path you want

Comment: at least tell us how is your current url format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

This will return an array with all the information related to the path. You should be able to see what is returned by doing `print_r($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);`

Hope this helps.