# Pass url from current page to controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I tried to pass url from current page to controller but it dosen't show me full url.

EX, `http://xxxxxx.localhost/cards/card_list/page:2` when i echo it in controller it shows `xxxxxx.localhost`. I knew because of the special character such as `("/" ":" )`...etc.

My project purpose is pass url with the form to controller after controller finished the work, I will redirect it to the current page.

card_list (View)

```
<?php echo $url5 = urlencode(Router::url($this->here, true)); ?>
<?php echo $form->create('CardSaleAll', array('url'=> array('controller' => 'cards', 'action' => 'complete_sale_card', $url5)));?>
<input type="hidden" name="data[CardSaleAll][sale_card_id]" value="'+id+'"> 
<?php echo $form->submit('Submit', array('alt' => '売却','type' => 'image', 'src' => '../../img/btn_52.png', 'style' => 'width: 307px;'));?>
```

cards (controller) => complete_sale_all (action)

```
function complete_sale_card($url5){
    echo $url5;
    exit();
}
```

Comment: does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189113/how-do-i-get-current-page-full-url-in-php-on-a-windows-iis-server

Answer (score 1):

Give the following a try

```
$this->request->url
```

The above should contain the URL as part of the current request for a view.

Comment: yes, echo first because I want to see the string right or wrong.

Comment: Try echo $this->request and see if the url is in there?

Comment: "Nothing to display" doesn't make any sense - it's impossible for the request url to be blank. Are you putting `echo $this->request->url` inside your `complete_sale_card` action?

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] might help

Comment: @AccessDenied Everything are work fine in `View` But it is bad in controller.

Comment: can u try a var_dump($this->request->data) and chk.. also u might have to try to set this to a variable and access it via the corresponding view

Comment: $this->request or any sorts should work in both view and controller

Answer (score 0):

### Use a greedy-star route

Normally a forward slash denotes a parameter delimiter:

I.e. the url `/controller/action/one/two/three/four` maps to the following variables:

```
function action ($one, $two, $three, $four) {
}
```

If you want `$one` to contain everything that follows the action name (in the above example) you can use a [greedy-star](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes) route:

```
Router::connect(
    '/anything/**',
    array('controller' => 'cards', 'action' => 'complete_sale_card')
);
```

### Or make life simple

Instead of putting a url in the url, you can just make it a form field:

```
<?php 
echo $form->create('CardSaleAll', array(
    'action' => 'complete_sale_card'
));
echo $form->input('redirect', array(
    'type'=> 'hidden',
    'value' => $url5
));
?>
```

### Don't mix raw html with the form helper

In the question there is this snippet:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[CardSaleAll][sale_card_id]" value="'+id+'">
```

As well as being an error (unless `id` really is a constant) it's a bad idea to write inputs by hand instead of letting cake generate them for you. If nothing else, because it's very easy to generate invalid markup or allow injection attacks. Instead replace with:

```
echo $this->Form->input('sale_card_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
```

Or similar.

### Don't use relative urls

In the question there's also this:

> 'src' => '../../img/btn_52.png', 'style' => 'width: 307px;'

That's also a bad idea.

This will work for the url `http://xxxxxx.localhost/cards/card_list/` (I assume) and fail for the url `http://xxxxxx.localhost/cards/card_list` (no trailing slash).

Instead:

1. Use css where appropriate - this is an example of where it is appropriate
2. if you really want to put a url in your source code, use `Router::url()` to generate the right *absolute* url.